# Is it feasible to mount a 16GB image on a virtual machine?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

I'm currently working on 32-bit VMware, running Ubuntu. I was thinking of switching to a 64-bit virtual machine, because I’d like to do some cross platform development for the Raspberry PI without switching OSs (my other work require me to use Windows).

I need an image of the card mounted for cross compiling. I usually do this on Ubuntu running on the host, and I was wondering will anything prevent me from mounting a 16GB image (that’s the size of the SD card), on a virtual machine. Will it cause the virtual machine to get too slow? Is this kind of thing feasible?

EDIT: I'm more concerned of having a one large file (16G), not the size of the harddisk. I assume the VM splits files to smaller sizes to store it on disk. I'm not sure.

I’d like to know your thoughts before going down this path. Thanks!

Comment: I think I didn't address my main concern in the question. I'm more concerned of having a one large file (16G), not the size of the harddisk. I assume the VM splits files to smaller sizes to store it on disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a large disk on a VM will make no appreciable difference to its performance.

The only place it could be an issue is if you are doing a lot of reads/writes on a number of VM's, which will cause the OS to bottleneck, but simply having the resource mounted is neither here nor there.

Comment: I'm more concerned of having a one large file (16G), not the size of the harddisk. I assume the VM splits files to smaller sizes to store it on disk. I'm not sure.

Comment: VMware only splits hard disk images it creates if you select to do so. [It is perfectly capable of supporting single-file virtual disks up to 1.9 TB](http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-12/topic/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-CFBC64DD-E9BE-42E2-9462-453A13AB8442.html).

Answer (score 0):

That's a very general question - what's the image suppose to do? How many resources will it consume? What version are you installing?

I don't think the sheer size should make any difference. It's the use that's gonna crash the VM - and dev work is always chip-intensive. I suggest to give it a go, and come back here with some speed tests for us to optimise.